# Web App that uses a database from a seperate API

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, reactjs, api-design

I'm in the process of creating a web app and native mobile apps. I've done a good amount of research and the best approach so far is to set up a separate API to handle a shared database between the web app and the mobile apps. Essentially, the database will be seperate from the web app.

For the web app, our stack is going to be React/Rails. I was wondering if someone could clarify ( what is probably really obvious ) how the rails controllers are going to communicate with the separate API ?

How will we render the components from the API database?

I'm probably over complicating things, but I could use some help.

Comment: Wait are you saying that the database is separate from the web app  "Because the database isn't on the web app"

Comment: Yes, Im going to edit the post to make that very clear. The database will be seperate from the web app.

Comment: Why do you mean by 'Rails in a mobile app'? Mobile apps are typically java (android) or objective-c / swift (ios) applications.

Comment: @azium Edit... Should say "web app" not mobile app... Mobile apps are being written in React Native.

Comment: If your web frontend is react, what do you even need rails app for? Serve static react files? React app can just go to the api, like the mobile clients.

Comment: Agreed with @SergioTulentsev the Rails server doesn't seem to serve any purpose at the moment. Maybe you have a good reason to use it, but serving React shouldn't be one of them.